# Why is functional component nested function using a stale state value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures, intersection-observer, use-ref

My component fetches and displays posts using infinite scrolling (via an `IntersectionObserver`). The API call that the component makes is dependent on the current number of fetched posts. This is passed as an offset to the API call.

The desired effect is that, if the `posts` array is empty, its length is 0 and my API will return the first 5 posts. When the last post in the UI intersects with the viewport, another fetch is made, but this time the API call is passed an offset of 5, so the API skips the first 5 posts in the collection and returns the next 5 instead.

Here is my code:

```
export default function Feed() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  const fetchPosts = async () => {
    const newPosts = await postAPI.getFeed(posts.length);
    setPosts((prevPosts) => [...prevPosts, ...newPosts]);
  };

  useEffect(fetchPosts, []);

  const observerRef = useRef(
    new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        observerRef.current.unobserve(entry.target);
        fetchPosts();
      }
    })
  );

  const observePost = useCallback((node) => node && observerRef.current.observe(node), []);

  return (
    <>
      {posts.map((post) => {
        const key = post._id;
        const isLastPost = key === posts.at(-1)._id;
        const callbackRef = !isLastPost ? undefined : observePost; //only if last post in state, watch it!
        
        return <PostCard {...{ key, post, callbackRef }} />;
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

However, every time the `fetchPosts` function is called, the value it uses for `posts.length` is 0 - the number the function was originally created with.

Can someone explain to me why the closure over `posts.length` is stale here? I thought that every time a component re-renders, all nested functions within it were recreated from scratch? As such, surely the `fetchPosts` function should be using the latest value of `posts.length` every time it is called? Any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a `new IntersectionObserver` on every render - not a good idea. However, only the first of all these created observers, the one you store in the ref (the ref that is never updated), is the one on which you call `observe()`, and that first observer uses a stale closure over the initial value of `posts`.

Instead, I would suggest creating the intersection observer(s) inside the `observePost` function:

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

const fetchPosts = useCallback(async () => {
  const newPosts = await postAPI.getFeed(posts.length);
  setPosts((prevPosts) => [...prevPosts, ...newPosts]);
}, [posts.length]);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^

useEffect(fetchPosts, []);

const observePost = useCallback((node) => {
  if (!node) return;
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      observer.unobserve(entry.target);
      fetchPosts();
    }
  });
  observer.observe(node);
}, [fetchPosts]);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Important here is the dependency of the `observePost` callback on the `fetchPosts` callback which has a dependency on the length of `posts`, to avoid getting stale. It's probably also possible to solve this with refs, but I don't think they're necessary here.

Comment: hi can you explain why I am creating a new observer on every render here? I thought that storing the returned observer instance in a ref would prevent that? Thank you

Comment: @AlexT It's still getting created and passed to `useRef` as an argument. `useRef` will ignore any put the first one, but they still get created and immediately garbage-collected.

Comment: Oh thank you. I didn't know that useRef() worked that way. Useful information. I presume all React hooks are like this then? For example, if we pass an initial state value to the `useState` hook, it will still be parsed on subsequent renders, but ignored and garbage-collected?

Comment: Yes, that's just how JavaScript works, there's nothing React can do about that. For `useState` specifically, they do have a lazy initialisation pattern though, where you can pass a function that will be called only once to create an initial value.

Comment: I have just read your suggested solution. Is the creation of a new `IntersectionObserver` every time we want to observe a `PostCard` necessary? And are you sure that we don't need to maintain a reference to the previous observer so that we can `disconnect` it when a new instance of the last `PostCard` mounts?

Comment: No, it's probably not necessary, but I don't think it would hurt. If you want to reuse one and the same instance, with the same handler callback, that handler would need to call the current `fetchPosts` through a ref. As for disconnecting, I thought that's unnecessary when the observed element is unmounted; your original code didn't do it either and I wasn't sure when and how `callbackRef` is called. But indeed it might be a problem if a additional PostCards are mounted and the observer is kept, observing a node that is no longer the last one.